# Can we use pom.xml into ANT

Tags: ant, maven, ivy, pom.xml, build.xml

I know that, we can very well use ANT and Maven together to build the project.We can run ANT scripts through Maven's POM.xml. But my question is can we run pom.xml through ANT's build.xml ?
i.e. can we create maven build from build.xml

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, using [maven ant tasks](http://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/index.html).

The page lists out multiple maven tasks which can be integrated into an ant build script, thus combining the features of both.  To take an example, there is the [mvn task](http://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/examples/mvn.html), which as documented can do a full maven build from ant.

```
  <artifact:mvn mavenHome="/path/to/maven-3.0.x">
     <arg value="install"/>
  </artifact:mvn>
```

Besides this, there are

- Dependencies task
- Install and Deploy tasks
- Pom task

each described with examples.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @Raghuram, Thanks for the link. But can you elaborate your answer with the help of any example, please

Comment: @Gaurav. Actually the link has all the info you need. I've elaborated the answer anyway.  Do edit your question with specific info you need and someone can help.

Answer (score 1):

[Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) and [ANT](http://ant.apache.org/) are very different build tools. In ANT you write all the logic yourself, whereas a standard build process is "baked in" with Maven.
The POM file contains no logic, instead it contains a series of declarations about your project.

If you understand well how Maven works, it is theoretically possible to take a POM and generate an ANT build that emulates the behaviour of the Maven build. I'm not aware of any solution which can easily convert in the other direction, mainly because ANT is missing Maven functionality, such as dependency management.

Instead of trying to convert an ANT build into Maven, I'd recommend that you keep your existing build logic and delegate the management of your classpath to the [ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) or [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/index.html) ANT tasks. These tools also provide tasks to publish your build output to a Maven repository, enabling your project to share with other projects using Maven.

Finally, I'm an [ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) advocate and wrote an [ant2ivy](https://github.com/myspotontheweb/ant2ivy) script which can assist in upgrade process. It creates an initial set of configuration files for downloading your projects dependencies from the Maven central repository.