# How to call for a Maven goal within an Ant script?

Tags: java, ant, maven

Is it possible to call or execute a Maven goal within an Ant script?

Say I have an ant target called 'distribute' and inside which I need to call a maven 'compile' goal from another pom.xml.

Comment: Can't you just compile the sources you need from ant ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

An example of use of exec task utilizing Maven run from the Windows CLI would be:

```
<target name="buildProject" description="Builds the individual project">
    <exec dir="${source.dir}\${projectName}" executable="cmd">
        <arg value="/C"/>
        <arg value="${env.MAVEN_HOME}\bin\mvn.bat"/>
        <arg line="clean install" />
</exec>
</target>
```

Comment: My requirement is I have old project which is build on ant and I have new project which is build on maven. I want build maven project from ant using build.xml. I used this and build my project but it did not work for me. My old project build successfully but new project did not.

Answer (score 37):

Since none of the solutions worked for me, this is what I came up with:

Assuming you are running on Windows:

```
<target name="mvn">
    <exec dir="." executable="cmd">
        <arg line="/c mvn clean install" />
    </exec>
</target>
```

or on UNIX:

```
<target name="mvn">
    <exec dir="." executable="sh">
        <arg line="-c 'mvn clean install'" />
    </exec>
</target>
```

or if you want it to work on both UNIX and Windows:

```
<condition property="isWindows">
    <os family="windows" />
</condition>

<condition property="isUnix">
    <os family="unix" />
</condition>

<target name="all" depends="mvn_windows, mvn_unix"/>

<target name="mvn_windows" if="isWindows">
    <exec dir="." executable="cmd">
        <arg line="/c mvn clean install" />
    </exec>
</target>

<target name="mvn_unix" if="isUnix">
    <exec dir="." executable="sh">
        <arg line="-c 'mvn clean install'" />
    </exec>
</target>
```

Comment: I copy  <target name="mvn">
      <exec dir="." executable="cmd">
        <arg line="/c mvn clean install" />
     </exec>  this in my build.xml and run ant all through cmd but pom.xml did not build. can you please tell what is wrong ?
</target>

Comment: @pankaj submit a new question for your problem

Comment: @pankaj Did you add mvn target as depends or default target? New topic would be nice

Answer (score 12):

You can also look at [maven ant tasks](http://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/index.html) which is now retired though as commented below.  This allows you to run specific maven goals from within your ant build script.  You can look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7552895/can-we-use-pom-xml-into-ant/) as well.

Comment: Maven Ant Tasks are now retired

Answer (score 9):

You may use a `java` task (this example is similar to @mateusz.fiolka answer but also works on Linux)

```
<target name="mvn-install">
    <property environment="env" />
    <path id="classpath">
        <fileset dir="${env.M2_HOME}/boot">
            <include name="plexus-classworlds-*.jar" />
        </fileset>
    </path>
    <property name="mvn.mainclass" value="org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher" />

    <java classname="${mvn.mainclass}" classpathref="classpath" fork="true" failonerror="true">
        <jvmarg value="-Dclassworlds.conf=${env.M2_HOME}/bin/m2.conf" />
        <jvmarg value="-Dmaven.home=${env.M2_HOME}" />
        <arg value="install" />
    </java>
</target>
```

tested with maven 3.0.5

Answer (score 5):

Here there is a complete solution:

```
<target name="mvn_windows_setup" if="isWindows">
    <property name="mvn.executable" value="cmd" />
    <property name="mvn.args" value="/c" />
</target>

<target name="mvn_unix_setup" if="isUnix">
    <property name="mvn.executable" value="sh" />
    <property name="mvn.args" value="-c" />
</target>

<target name="run-mvn-goals" depends="mvn_windows_setup, mvn_unix_setup">

    <exec dir="${basedir}" executable="${mvn.executable}">
        <arg line="${mvn.args} 'mvn ${p_goals}'" />
    </exec>

</target>

<!-- EXAMPLES OF HOW TO USE -->

<!-- let's say you want to run mvn clean install -->
<target name="mvn-clean-install">

    <antcall target="run-mvn-goals">
        <param name="p_goals" value="clean install"/>
    </antcall>
</target>

<!-- or maybe you want to clean, package but skipping tests -->
<target name="mvn-clean-package-notests">

    <antcall target="run-mvn-goals">
        <param name="p_goals" value="clean package -DskipTests"/>
    </antcall>
</target>
```

The output is something like this...

```
Buildfile: /home/.../build.xml
deploy-complete:
deploy-complete:
mvn_windows_setup:
mvn_unix_setup:
run-mvn-goals:
     [exec] [INFO] Scanning for projects...
     [exec] [INFO]                                                                         
     [exec] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
     [exec] [INFO] Building wpm 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
     [exec] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
     [exec] [INFO] 
     [exec] [INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.6.1:clean (default-clean) @ wpm ---
     ...
     ...
     ...
       [exec] [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
     [exec] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
     [exec] [INFO] Total time: 28.817 s
     [exec] [INFO] Finished at: 2016-11-14T14:01:34-05:00
     [exec] [INFO] Final Memory: 84M/872M
     [exec] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 31 seconds
```

Answer (score 2):

I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23060549/875305) from [@Adam Siemion](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2345933/adam-siemion) above, but I didn't want separate targets for running on Windows or Linux. Instead I just set the property near the top of my ant script:

```
<condition property="isAntRunningOnWindows">
    <os family="windows" />
</condition>
```

Then in the middle of my script I use an if-then-else statement:

```
<if>
    <equals arg1="${isAntRunningOnWindows}" arg2="true" />
    <then>
        <echo message="OS is Windows" />
        <exec dir="." executable="cmd">
            <arg line="/c mvn clean package" />
        </exec>
    </then>
    <else>
        <echo message="OS is Linux/Unix" />
        <exec dir="." executable="sh">
            <arg line="-c 'mvn clean package'" />
        </exec>
    </else>
</if>
```

Answer (score 2):

I am using the following target to run maven `clean`, `install` and `clean install` goals. Works fine.

```
<project name="Maven run goals" basedir="."  
         xmlns:artifact="antlib:org.apache.maven.artifact.ant"
         xmlns:rsel="antlib:org.apache.tools.ant.types.resources.selectors">

    <target name="maven clean">
        <artifact:mvn mavenHome="${maven.home}" fork="true">
            <arg value="clean" />
        </artifact:mvn>
    </target>

    <target name="maven install">
        <artifact:mvn mavenHome="${maven.home}" fork="true">
            <arg value="install" />
        </artifact:mvn>
    </target>

    <target name="maven clean-install">
        <artifact:mvn mavenHome="${maven.home}" fork="true">
            <arg value="clean" />
            <arg value="install" />
        </artifact:mvn>
    </target>

</project>
```

Your maven.home property should point to the maven home directory. For example,

```
<property name="maven.home" value="D:\\Downloads\\apache-maven-3.0.5"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [exec task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) and call `mvn compile` as a terminal command. This is not ideal since you won't have any control over the execution, but otherwise I don't think there is a way to execute a Maven goal.

Answer (score 1):

#### Maven Ant Tasks <sup>[github](https://github.com/apache/maven-ant-tasks)</sup> easy to run maven with goals form Ant.

[Installation](http://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/installation.html)
Create a `lib` directory in the root of your project and place the **maven-ant-tasks.jar**<sup>[binaries](http://archive.apache.org/dist/maven/ant-tasks/2.1.3/binaries/), [sonatype](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.apache.maven/maven-ant-tasks/2.1.3/jar)</sup> file inside it.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project name="maven" default="build" xmlns:artifact="antlib:org.apache.maven.artifact.ant">
    <property environment="env" />

    <!-- <get src="http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/apache/maven/maven-ant-tasks/2.1.3/maven-ant-tasks-2.1.3.jar" dest="lib/maven-ant-tasks-2.1.3.jar"/> -->

    <path id="maven-ant-tasks.classpath" path="lib/maven-ant-tasks-2.1.3.jar" />
    <typedef resource="org/apache/maven/artifact/ant/antlib.xml" uri="antlib:org.apache.maven.artifact.ant" classpathref="maven-ant-tasks.classpath" />

    <record name="build.log" loglevel="verbose" action="start"/>
    <target name="build" description="project build ant script">
        <fail unless="env.MAVEN_HOME" message="Environment variable MAVEN_HOME was not found on your system!" />
        <artifact:mvn mavenHome="${env.MAVEN_HOME}" fork="true">
            <arg value="clean" />
            <arg value="install" />
            <arg value="-Pqa" />
        </artifact:mvn>
    </target>
</project>
```

---

Small information between these elements ant `typedef` vs `taskdef`.

- **[`Typedef`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/typedef.html)**: Using a `typedef` declaration allows you to store the Ant Tasks' library anywhere you like (such as source control) and put it's location in the build file.

  ```xml
  <typedef name="urlset" classname="com.mydomain.URLSet"/>
  ```
- **[`Taskdef`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/taskdef.html)** Adds a task definition to the current project, such that this new task can be used in the current project.

  Using [PropertyFiles.java](https://github.com/Yash-777/LearnJava/blob/master/src/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/optional/PropertyFiles.java) task by adding it to taskdef externally.

  ```xml
  <taskdef name = "propertyfiles"
        classname = "org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.PropertyFiles" />
  ```

  All the `taskdef` are configured in `apache-ant-1.9.4\lib\ant.jar\org\apache\tools\ant\taskdefs\defaults.properties` properties files. But i have created an external class and placed inside jar file. But instead of adding  entry in `defaults.properties` file externally informing the task by `taskdef`.

  Second way, You can create a jar file, list all the `tasksef` in one properties file and refer the resource
  [**antcontrib**](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/) You can place the JAR in your Ant lib directory, and set classpath.

  ```xml
  <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties">
      <classpath>
          <pathelement location="${env.ANT_HOME}/lib/ant-contrib-0.6.jar"/>
      </classpath>
  </taskdef>
  ```

Answer (score 1):

This is an old post, but still relevant (for me, anyhow). I think things have changed since the original post. Turns out the solution is quite simple, and [you don't need all the ant-maven integration fluff](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MANTTASKS-201?focusedCommentId=15291978&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-15291978). It makes me wonder why this wasn't the answer 8 years ago, as I'm pretty sure it would have worked then as it does now. I should mention this is for Windows.  You could probably tweak it to support Unix or both.

1. Install maven for Windows
2. Create an environment variable MAVEN_HOME that points to the base mvn install directory (e.g., C:\dev\apache-maven-3.6.3)
3. Add this to your build.xml file:

> ```
> <property environment="env" />
> ```

4. Add this task to your build.xml:

> ```
> <target name="mvnPackage" description="Creates war file">
>    <fail unless="env.MAVEN_HOME" message="Environment variable MAVEN_HOME was not found on your system!" />
>    <exec executable="${env.MAVEN_HOME}\bin\mvn.cmd">
>        <arg value="clean" />
>        <arg value="package" />
>    </exec>
> </target>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

From Thiagoh answer, I have to add this to make it work.

```
 <condition property="isWindows">
                    <os family="windows" />
 </condition>

 <condition property="isLinux">
                    <os family="unix" />
 </condition>

<target name="mvn_windows_setup" if="isWindows">
    <property name="mvn.executable" value="cmd" />
    <property name="mvn.args" value="/c" />
</target>

<target name="mvn_unix_setup" if="isLinux">
    <property name="mvn.executable" value="sh" />
    <property name="mvn.args" value="-c" />
</target>

<target name="run-mvn-goals" depends="mvn_windows_setup, mvn_unix_setup">

    <exec dir="${basedir}" executable="${mvn.executable}">
        <arg line="${mvn.args} 'mvn ${p_goals}'" />
    </exec>

</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

`plexus` seems to be an older solution for embedding Maven.

Take a look at the [Apache's Maven Embedder](https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-embedder/index.html) project.

[This article paragraph](https://www.sourcetrail.com/blog/how_to_integrate_maven_into_your_own_java_tool#using-maven-embedder) outlines embedding Maven into Java code, ***without*** a locally installed Maven executable.