# Is it possible to define a pom.xml in a subdirectory (instead that in the project root)?

Tags: java, maven, svn, maven-3, pom.xml

I have used MAVEN in my recent projects, and I'd like to keep using it also now that I'm on a project published under an SVN Repository **with Hooks** checking for a particular structure (ANT + IVY related) **that allows a `build.xml` in `/` (the project root), but not a `pom.xml`**.

**Can I place the `pom.xml` in `/src`** ?

Is there something I should modify inside the pom to make it aware of this ?

Comment: I guess this is theoretically possible but I can't even begin to imagine all the things that are going to go wrong. Everything in Maven is relative to the POM's location.

Comment: Damn... isn't there a setting like ANT's `basedir` in MAVEN ? :(( Stupid SVN hooks

Comment: Maven 's approach is "Convention over configuration", therefore it enforces a standard folder layout that helps all programmers as well as tool developers to work efficiently. Even if there is a way to configure this, it would be not the best approach to do. It would be best to use IVY together with ANT to work with the rest of the project.

Comment: @Spyros: it is the only way I can use Maven on this project, unless doing strange things like using a non-committed pom.xml in the root, committing it elsewhere and alerting everyone working on the project that it must be moved to the root after checking out and after every update :/

Comment: Simply change the SVN hooks cause they don't make sense...prevent developers from working...Apart from that accept the convention over configuration in Maven otherwise don't use it...

Comment: @khmarbaise I'm fighting since years for that, but normally I'm on another repo where I do whatever I want, so the problems arise only when we land in this sad part of the company :)

Comment: @AndreaLigios Based on your other comments and discussion I can see you do have an arguable motivation to find an answer to your question and you are doing it using a formal answer. This is why I upvoted this question.

Comment: **I'VE OBTAINED THE REMOVAL OF THE HOOKS !!!** I guess the question will be useful to people not lucky like me, I suppose :) Thanks to all

Answer (score 3):

> Try to use option `-f` when running maven:
>
> ```
> mvn -f src/pom.xml
> ```
>
> I personally have not tried this but hopefully it should work.

HOWEVER, WHY?

I'd recommend you to stop and rethink your requirements again. One of the advantages of maven is its default configuration. Once you are going according to the standards dictated by maven you do not have problems with various plugins etc.

EDIT.

I tried and saw that my first suggestion does not work. In order to make it working you have to update other parameters, e.g. source location. I still believe it is possible but I'd suggest you something else.

Put your pom.xml to source folder if SVN does not allow you to put it somewhere else. Also create batch file or shell script (depending on your platform) that copies the pom.xml to root directory, runs `mvn` and then removes pom.xml from root directory. IMHO this solution is clear and simple.

Comment: I don't think this will work. The basedir will be `src` and everything will be broken (Maven will look for sources inside `src/src/main/java` and whatnot).

Comment: @AlexR: the WHY is described in the question: I'm on a SVN repository that doesn't allow me to commit a POM.XML in the root. Normally I'm on another SVN repository that allows me to do it.

Comment: I have tried my suggestion and found it does not work. I am going to update my answer with other suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the `-f src` option to select a directory the pom is in. See the Source of maven for details:

```
    String alternatePomFile = null;
    if ( commandLine.hasOption( CLIManager.ALTERNATE_POM_FILE ) )
    {
        alternatePomFile = commandLine.getOptionValue( CLIManager.ALTERNATE_POM_FILE ); // -f
    }

    ...

    if ( alternatePomFile != null )
    {
        File pom = resolveFile( new File( alternatePomFile ), workingDirectory );
        if ( pom.isDirectory() )
        {
            pom = new File( pom, "pom.xml" );
        }

        request.setPom( pom );
    }
```

Comment: Yes you can, but then nothing will work, according to the tests (and comments) from the other answer; I've upvoted that because he has tried the solution, saving my time from doing it, and then edited the answer saying that it doesn't work; I won't upvote this because future visitors could interpret positive answers like working answers, while this is not (unless proven wrong). However, thanks for your time (I always like answers with source code in them)

Comment: Wait, i found `src/src` in the compile-folder

Comment: Maybe you can drop the contents of the `build.xml` and paste the `pom.xml` into the `build.xml`. Then a `mvn clean install -f build.xml` would work.

Answer (score 1):

There should be several (evil) ways to go around the restrictions imposed by the hooks and what we are looking is for is the lesser evil.
The key requirements are:
-You must use an ANT/IVY structure.
-You cannot have a formal Maven structure with the pom.xml.
-You have to use Maven.

If I really had no other option I would create an ant task to copy the file 
from somewhere I could legaly save it to the place it was meant to be found.
See: https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html

And an ant task that runs maven.
See: [How to call for a Maven goal within an Ant script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7581156/how-to-call-for-a-maven-goal-within-an-ant-script)

Everyone would use this exact ant script that does these two steps.
I would describe this procedure in a readme file and explain why this has to be done.

Advantages: Automated, clear solution that can be easily converted to a maven project later. After the pom.xml has been created one can just use MAVEN. However I would recommend that you always use ant to call MAVEN to avoid having to manually monitor changes in the pom.xml. (You need to call ANT at least once after the pom.xml has been updated.)

Disadvantages: Group of programmers would need to familiarize with this informal process, uses also ANT.

Comment: I like this, +1. Meanwhile I've talked with the system engineers and they're discussing about the possibility of removing the hooks for my project... up to last year it would have been impossible, let's cross the fingers and hope :)

Comment: Removing the hooks would be, by far the best approach. I hope they are removed.

Comment: Read the last comment to the question :)